# Bug in Plotly Subplots for R using more then 9 plots

Tags: plotly

If I execute this code, using `qtySubPlots <- 9`:

```
library(plotly)

p <- plot_ly(economics, x = date, y = uempmed)

qtySubPlots <- 9
options <- list(nrows=4)
plots <- lapply(seq(1,qtySubPlots), function(x) {p})
do.call(subplot, c(plots,options))
```

I get this beautiful grid:

[image]

Now setting `qtySubPlots` for any value greater then 9 (for example 10) I get:

[image]

Any clue how to solve that?

[Issue #427](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/427)